# How to execute a javascript code after loading the fancybox?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

How to execute a JavaScript code after loading the fancybox?
I have a menu (ul li) that appears in a fancybox, I will run a JavaScript code after clicking the `<LI>`
I found this script that did not reach my expectations within the application!

Any help please?

My code :

```js
function initFancybox(){
    $('.lightboxX').fancybox({
        autoSize: false,
        width: 800,
        overlayColor: '#fff',
        showCloseButton: (!$(this).attr('data-close')) || ('true' === $(this).data('close')),
        modal: !!$(this).attr('data-close'),
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterLoad: function(){
             // CODE JAVASCRIPT 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What javascript code are you needing to load inside the fancybox? Can you show the menu (ul li) part of the code inside the fancybox?

Comment: Right now your callback function 'afterLoad' is empty. Have you been able to console.log something here? If not, you could try beforeShow instead.

Comment: i haven't able to console.log  as well as with BeforeShow Callback.